# My VSCode showing this error everytime while i first open it. Can anyone help me on this please

Tags: visual-studio-code

There was an error while attempting to kill any running Code.exe processes:

Failed to open process: access denied

Comment: have you used the task manager to kill all running VSC processes after closing VSC

Comment: No i never done that